# Как вывести скидку на товар в правильном виде?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce

Есть магазин с товарами на wordpress+woocommerce. Пробую посчитать скидку на товар при распродаже, но что-то не получается - на выходе получаю формат `1.35`а не `1.350` руб..Что делаю не так?

```
<p class="economy">
  <?php 
   function extract_unit($string, $start, $end)
   {
      $pos = stripos($string, $start);
      $str = substr($string, $pos);
      $str_two = substr($str, strlen($start));
      $second_pos = stripos($str_two, $end);
      $str_three = substr($str_two, 0, $second_pos);
      $unit = trim($str_three); // remove whitespaces
      return $unit;
    }
   global $product; 
   $price=$product->get_price_html(); 
   $saleprice = extract_unit($price,'<ins><span class="amount">','<ruble title="руб.">a</ruble></span></ins>');
   $regprice = extract_unit($price,'<del><span class="amount">','<ruble title="руб.">a</ruble></span></del>');     
   $economy= $regprice - $saleprice;
   echo $economy." <ruble title='руб.'>a</ruble>"; ?>
</p>

echo $product->get_price_html();
```

выводится в таком виде:

```
<p class="price">
  <del><span class="amount">21.150&nbsp;<ruble title="руб.">a</ruble>
  </span></del>
  <ins><span class="amount">19.800&nbsp;<ruble title="руб.">a</ruble>
  </span></ins>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте sprintf:

Вместо 
`echo $economy." <ruble title='руб.'>a</ruble>";`

Попробуйте
`echo sprintf("%.3f"." <ruble title='руб.'>a</ruble>", $economy);`

```
$number = 1234.56; 

// английский формат (по умолчанию)
$english_format_number = number_format($number);
// 1,234

// французский формат
$nombre_format_francais = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');
// 1 234,56

$number = 1234.5678;
// английский формат без разделителей групп
$english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
// 1234.57
```

Источник: [php.net](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.number-format.php)

Comment: получается так: `1350.000&nbsp;` это совсем не то, что мне нужно - точка должна разделять тысячи, а не дробить на копейки, т.е. нужно получит так  `1.350&nbsp;`

Comment: ну, тогда можно попробовать `number_format`

Comment: это как записать - поясните плиз

Comment: пишу так -`number_format($economy,2,'','.');` ничего не выходит

Comment: все, разобрался - надо так `$number = number_format($economy,0,'','.'); echo $number." <ruble title='руб.'>a</ruble>";`